# What does "fully qualified" mean by itself and how it can be used?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I know this phrase from usage with DNS as Fully Qualified Domain Name but that's the only use case I'm aware of.

So, 1. I'm wondering what "Fully Qualified" means by itself and how it is applicable to other subjects.

and 2. is "fully qualified" and "unambiguous" interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully Qualified means that whatever it is has all the qualifications which are applicable. This could mean a qualification such as an FQDN has:

> **qualified** *adjective*
>   **2** not complete or absolute; limited
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/qualified)

That is, a fully-qualified domain name is limited to a *specific* domain, and that limitation in scope is sufficiently stringent to make it unambiguous.

But they could be academic or vocational qualifications:

> **qualified** *adjective*
>   **1** officially recognized as being trained to perform a particular job; certified
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/qualified)

[image: Fully Qualified Cosmetic Professionals]
[image: Fully Qualified Carpenter]

In these cases one would not talk of an "unambiguous carpenter".

Comment: I understand the case for "fully qualified carpenter" but I don't see how this apply to the FQDN.

Comment: +11 For this, I was trying to figure out how the original meaning of "qualified" was twisted by techies to mean that a FQDN was more "capable", but it's just a description of the *scope* of the domain name, that it's fully "narrowed".

Comment: @yaccz to your follow-up question, the "fully qualified" in FQDN relies on a different meaning of the word ("limited or modified in some way") than the "fully qualified carpenter" ("fitted (by training or experience) for a given purpose") ... see definitions here:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualified

Comment: @JeffSahol Yes, as in "qualified success"

Comment: I'm still having difficulty understanding the "not complete or absolute" part. In the case of FQDN it seem to me exactly opposite - FQDN is complete, absolute name.

Comment: "Not complete or absolute" is only really applicable to something like "qualified success". An FQDN is limited to an unambiguous entity; or maybe one might say that it doesn't apply to all servers within a domain? *Qualified* in FQDN is technical jargon, and doesn't necessarily fit exactly with ordinary English -- although there is some resemblance (as illustrated by "limited").

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary: *Qualification*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qualification) meaning 4 applies to the carpenter, while meaning 1 applies to the Domain Name.  The *Fully* just means that there are no more qualifications required to make someone suitable for the work, or to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Please note the following advice in the Help section and supplement your answer accordingly.  **Provide context for links** : Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Answer (score 0):

If one uses the Merriam-Webster definition of "qualified":
***to characterize by naming an attribute***
Then, it seems that "fully qualified" would mean:
***To characterize by naming all attributes.***
And, that would suggest that there's a standard or agreement as to what "all" means.
So, an FQDN example would have "all" as:
Top level domain (TLD) like .com
Second level domain names (SLD) like "google" for which there may be more than one.
Then perhaps a host name like "mymail" or "www".
And stating the value of each one makes it Fully Qualified, i.e. having all of the attributes stated.
We are used to fully qualified postal addresses when we add USA, North America, Planet Earth, etc. where practice suggests that the continent AND the country needn't both be used and adding the planet is silly.  So, one could argue that such addresses aren't "fully qualified" depending on what rules we like to use for "all".